# How do you fix error 0x8007000b in Windows Live Photo Gallery?

Tags: windows, windows-photo-gallery

When you start Windows Photo Gallery (formerly Windows Live Photo Gallery, now part of Microsoft Essentials 2012), you may receive the following errors, and the application will close:

Windows Live Photo Gallery encountered an error and can't start.
Error Code: 0x80070043

Comment: In my case, I'd moved the location of Videos and Images to another drive.
Try restoring the default libraries as described here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/documentslibrary-ms-is-no-longer-working/0845e8c3-4097-47e8-887a-ae875aa7c4b6

1. In Windows Explorer, go to **Libraries** and delete **Pictures** and **Videos** (you may also have to delete **Documents** and **Music**).
2. Right-click **Libraries** in the navigation pane, then select **Restore Default Libaries** from the context menul
3. Restart Windows Photo Gallery.

Comment: This should be given as an answer

Comment: I couldn't until just now (not enough reputation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have moved your My Photos/My Videos folder to another location, it seems Windows Photo Gallery gets confused.

Try restoring the default libraries as described here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/documentslibrary-ms-is-no-longer-working/0845e8c3-4097-47e8-887a-ae875aa7c4b6

1. In Windows Explorer, go to Libraries and delete Pictures and Videos (you may also have to delete Documents and Music).
2. Right-click Libraries in the navigation pane, then select Restore Default Libaries from the context menu.